# Как бороться с кастомными scrollview на некоторых прошивках?

Tags: android, java, прокрутка

Добрый день!
У меня вылетело из головы название этого эффекта, в связи с этим я потратил 2 дня на безуспешные поиски. На некоторый девайсах стоят прошивки не родные и из-за этого в элементах, которые могут прокручивать контент(в моем случае **scrollview**), появляется вот такой эффект, как на анимации ниже, от которого появляются проблемы в некоторых реализациях **pull-to-refresh**. Подскажите, возможно ли от него избавиться каким-то образом только в моем приложении соответственно не меняя прошивку?

**UPD:** здесь имеется ввиду не цветовой эффект, а кто, что swcrollview вытягивается за границы, а потом возвращается назад

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

android:overscrollHeader="@null" 
android:overscrollFooter="@null"

android:overScrollMode="never"
```

что-то из этого точно поможет. А как делается такая анимированая картинка?

Comment: это просто gif :) Я попросил дизайнера, он быстро собрал :)
Я не про цветовой эффект говорил, а про то, что scrollview вытягивается за границы и возвращается назад. Если вы правильно поняли, то подскажите, как программно задать overscrollFooter?

Comment: Так любят делать в Самсунг, что бы косить под айфон. Собственно у вторых есть некие патенты на это и они ими гоняли первых. Называется резиновые списки. Рекомендуется не переживать по этому поводу.

Comment: @KoVadim как не переживать то? у меня из-за таких вещей вылетает за границы scrollview

Comment: Я думаю, что проблема в коде, а не в резиновом списке.

А так как самсунгов много (это же самый продаваемый андроид производитель), то нужно искать проблему в коде.


У меня лично самсунг, но нормальный (Galaxy Nexus) - там нет этой проблемы. Но на других никогда не видел проблем с списком.

Comment: Да если бы все так просто было, у и проблема не на самсунгах, а на китайских моделях, а возможности отладки нет, да и код не мой, я взял лучшую реализацию pull-to-refresh, что нашел

Comment: тогда три варианта

 - раздобыть китайское чудо либо человека с ним и экспериментировать, снять логи, медитировать.
 - продолжать ныть и говорить "и девайса нет, и что делать не знаю".
 - забить на китайцев, если их девайсов не так много, а pull-to-refress отключить на этих устройствах.